# Is there a pythonic way to chain these function calls?

Tags: python

I have some code in which I end up with a list of binary functions and a list of values, and I need to chain the calls like so:

```
funs = [..]
vals = [..]

result = funs[0](vals[0],
           funs[1](vals[1],
               ..
               funs[-1](vals[-2], vals[-1])))))..)
```

For a simple example, if:

```
funs = [operator.add, operator.mul]
vals = [1, 2, 3]
```

Then `result` should end up evaluating `add(1, mul(2, 3))`, to yield 7. I can write a `for` loop to evaluate each intermediary result, which is at the same time easy and yet incredibly unsatisfying:

```
result = vals[-1]
for val, fun in reversed(zip(vals[:-1], funs)):
    result = fun(val, result)
```

What's the Pythonic way? Or is this just fine as is?

Comment: Personally I think what you have there looks perfect. It's very clear what's going on. Sometimes in the quest of making code "more pythonic", one can really just make it more of an unreadable mess.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but `for val, fun in reversed(zip(vals[:-1], ops)):` should probably be `for val, fun in reversed(zip(vals[:-1], funs)):`

Comment: hmm, it's like you need a counterpart to `reduce` that also changes functions, interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This seems very similar to what `reduce` does but the function used would be different each time, so one solution would be to create an object that uses a different function each time it is called:

```
class Cycled_Functions:
    def __init__(self,functions):
        self.functions = iter(functions)
    def __call__(self,*args,**kw):
        f = next(self.functions) #will raise StopIteration at some point
        return f(*args,**kw)
```

Then `Cycled_Functions(reversed(FUNCTIONS))` would be suitable for use with `reduce` to accomplish your task:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

funs = [operator.add, operator.mul]
vals = [1, 2, 3]

f = Cycled_Functions(reversed(funs))

print(reduce(f, reversed(vals)))
```

I still prefer the basic loop you have but this is an alternative I figured it was worth offering.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you provided seems Pythonic to me. I'm not sure why you assumed it's not. People have mentioned reduce() in the comments, but [reduce() is considered non-Pythonic by Guido van Rossum](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) and I'd suppose variations on it would be as well when an iterative solution is possible. For what it's worth, you could write it using reduce() like so though:

```
def foo(funs, vals):
    """
    >>> import operator
    >>> funs = [operator.add, operator.mul]
    >>> vals = [1, 2, 3]
    >>> foo(funs, vals)
    7
    """
    return reduce(lambda z, (fun, val): fun(val, z), reversed(zip(funs, vals[:-1])), vals[-1])
```

For illustration, you could write it as a recursive function, but recursion is slower than iteration and constrained by a limit on the size of the call stack.

```
def foo(funs, vals):
    """
    >>> import operator
    >>> funs = [operator.add, operator.mul]
    >>> vals = [1, 2, 3]
    >>> foo(funs, vals)
    7
    """
    if len(funs) > 1:
        fun, val = funs[0], vals[0]
        return fun(val, foo(funs[1:], vals[1:]))
    else:
        [fun] = funs
        return fun(*vals)
```